# Azure Web App giving 'Access is Denied' error when trying to connect to Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, ldap

I am working on setting up an active directory integration for one of my clients. This is an Umbraco site, and I have the membership provider set up in my web config. When I run the site locally, everything works correctly. But when I deploy to an azure web app, I get a server error that says "Access is Denied".

I've tried googling and have tried the suggested fixes, but nothing changes the error that I'm getting.

```
<add name="ActiveDirectory" connectionString="LDAP://xx.xx.xx.xx:389/CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" />
<add name="ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" type="RB.ActiveDirectoryProviders.ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider, RB.ActiveDirectoryProviders" connectionStringName="ActiveDirectory" connectionUsername="domain\username" connectionPassword="password" groupsToUse="groups" />
```

Comment: Kerberos doesn't work over the Internet. Sync the local AD to Azure AD and integrate your Web App with Azure AD instead (OpenID Connect).

Comment: @evilSnobu If I am understanding the question, it appears he is having no trouble connecting to AD from a local dev machine over the internet, but it is not working from an Azure App Service.  I, too, am interested in this answer.

Comment: Any solution yet? I'm having a very similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your membership provider make sure the connectionUsername includes domain\username and just not the username